# C: Creating multiple instances of an enemy.?

Tags: c, struct, bgi

```
struct animate {
int drawable;
int animationFrames;
char *frames[TOTAL_FRAMES+1];
int charWidth;
int charHeight;
int xCoord;
int yCoord;
int xMove;
int yMove;
int currentFrame;
};
struct animate reaper[] =
{
{
    1,
    3,
    {
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_right_r.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_right_still.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_right_l.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_right_still.gif",
    },
    50,
    50,
    enemyx,
    enemyy,
    10,
    0,
    0,
},
{
    0,
    3,
    {
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_left_r.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_left_still.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_left_l.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_left_still.gif",
    },
    50,
    50,
    enemyx,
    enemyy,
    -10,
    0,
    0,
},
{
    0,
    3,
    {
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_up_r.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_up_still.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_up_l.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_up_still.gif",
    },
    50,
    50,
    enemyx,
    enemyy,
    0,
    -10,
    0,
},
{
    0,
    3,
    {
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_down_r.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_down_still.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_down_l.gif",
        "PIX\\Reaper\\reaper_down_still.gif",
    },
    50,
    50,
    enemyx,
    enemyy,
    0,
    10,
    0,
},
};

    void reaper_animation()
{

srand(time(NULL));
sprintf(charHealthBuff, "Health: %d", charHealth);
outtextxy(30, 30, charHealthBuff);
//randomly determines starting coordinates
enemyx = rand() % 100 + 600;
enemyy = rand() % 100 + 600;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    if( ! reaper[i].drawable)
        continue;
    //defines values of collisionBox struct
    reaperHit.boundx = reaper[i].xCoord;
    reaperHit.boundy = reaper[i].yCoord;
    reaperHit.boundheight = reaper[i].charHeight;
    reaperHit.boundwidth = reaper[i].charWidth;
    //Puts image of reaper on screen based on inputs from struct
readimagefile(reaper[i].frames[reaper[i].currentFrame],
    reaper[i].xCoord,
    reaper[i].yCoord,
    reaper[i].xCoord + reaper[i].charWidth,
    reaper[i].yCoord + reaper[i].charHeight );

reaper[i].currentFrame++; //increments the "frame" by one, thus only animating one image at a time
if(reaper[i].currentFrame == reaper[i].animationFrames){
    reaper[i].currentFrame = 0;} //When frame 3 is reached, it resorts back to first frame and restarts
    //character[i].drawable = 0;}

//increments reaper position based on xMove or yMove value
reaper[i].xCoord += reaper[i].xMove;
reaper[i].yCoord += reaper[i].yMove;
//harms character if this collision is true
if(collisionTest(reaperHit, charHit) == true){
    printf("reaper char COLLISION\n");
    charHealth = charHealth - 5;}
//harms reaper if this collision is true
if(collisionTest(thunderHit, reaperHit) == true){
    reaperHealth = reaperHealth - 10;}
}

}

void playReaper(){
int olddirection = 0, newdirection = 0; //starting values
int reaperDirection;
int moveLoop;
int activate = 0;
reaperHealth = 30;

do {
    srand(time(NULL));
    moveLoop = 10;
    reaperDirection = rand() % 4;
    //This loop keeps reaper going in same direction for more than one iteration
    for(int k = 0; k < moveLoop; k++){
    if(reaperDirection == 0)
        newdirection = 0;
    if(reaperDirection == 1)
        newdirection = 1;
    if(reaperDirection == 2)
        newdirection = 2;
    if(reaperDirection == 3)
        newdirection = 3;


if(olddirection != newdirection){
    reaper[newdirection].xCoord = reaper[olddirection].xCoord; //keeps xCoord and yCoord the same when changing directions
    reaper[newdirection].yCoord = reaper[olddirection].yCoord; //allowing sprite to stay where they were

    reaper[olddirection].drawable = 0; //the previous direction is no longer drawable
    reaper[newdirection].drawable = 1; //new direction becomes drawable and animated
    reaper[newdirection].currentFrame = 0; //resets frame to 0 so complete animation can begin
    if(newdirection == 0 || newdirection == 1 || newdirection == 2 || newdirection == 3){
    olddirection = newdirection;} //turns newdirection into olddirection for next run through of do-while() loop
}
checkReaperSectors(); //checks for sector collision and allows sector refresh

reaper_animation(); //animates the reaper

Sleep(40); //Slows reaper movement down 
    check_reaper(); //checks for collisions with wall or obstacles
    }
}
while(reaperHealth > 0);
if(reaperHealth <= 0){
    level++;}
}
```

Ok, this is rather long... lol but this is my entire code for handling my enemy animation, reaper. There are 4 defined structs that give each direction of reaper values to be called, the playReaper() function determines which struct to draw, then the animate reaper actually puts it on the screen.

The problem is... I can only get one reaper going at a time... I am trying to figure out how to work a class with this, but am worried if I changed reaper to class, I would have to change character, and boss to class as well? (they are handled under same style, using animate struct).

Or how might this be done creating an array of an array of structs. Like an array of 100 of struct animate reaper[]. This would create 100 ready to go individual reapers, then I can call in a certain number of them per level, then they will all appear randomly and move randomly about the screen.

It just is... I have no idea how to make classes really... so am definitely at a loss about how I would go about doing this one. I try to research online but it only goes so far... none of the examples seem to be like what I want to do so it is hard to apply them to my code (especially when never having done classes...).

I am also unsure of how to create an array of reaper[]'s. :(

Would anyone be able to guide me through what I must do? or at least give me a good starting point?

It would be HUGELY appreciated!!

p.s. this is simple top-down, 2d game and I am in graphics.h :/

Comment: If you make a struct `foo` that contains all the information about one reaper, then create an array of `foo` and you have many reapers.

Comment: Due to the way your functions are set up, it looks like you're modifying a single, global array called reaper. Instead, modify them to take an argument which contains all data on the reaper you want to create. However, I would highly recommend you rewrite this as a class in C++.

Comment: Haha... I attempted a class. I have never done c++ or classes before. It animated a reaper. But Could only get one? When my character killed one another popped up. I want like 5 at one time :(